# How to write a function that scales fonts automatically in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want a function can be scale fonts'size automatically to one row.
I know the following code can be scale manual

```
With .Paragraphs.First.Range.Font.Scaling = 41
end with
```

and I try to get the font's width,and calc the font spacing
but not the best solution

```
With .PageSetup
.PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(21)               
.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.8)              
.RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.6)
end with  
with 
.Paragraphs.First.Range.font.size = 60            
.Range.Font.Spacing = CentimetersToPoints(15.6) - (180 ^ (1 / 2)) * (.Range.Characters.Count - 1)) / (.Range.Characters.Count - 2)     'not correct
```

who can give the Complete and good code.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: You have enough reputation that one could expect you'd know the site rules, as explained in the [help]. But there have been so many low-quality questions from you in the past week I feel forced to comment, as you must be close to a question ban at this point. The problem descriptions in these questions are incomplete: it's never clear exactly what you're asking. Recent questions are not tagged with the application to which the question pertains. Quite honestly, I suspect that a major issue is inadequate English language skills for formulating  problems understandably...

Comment: Are you talking about font size, font spacing or alignment? Three different things. Do I understand correctly when you want the maximum font **SIZE** whilst still having your title in a single line in your cell? Furthermore, you have 17 questions with zero of them with a marked answer. Maybe look into that first!

Comment: just adjust the font Scaling,not size

Comment: Also voted to re-open. However, my previous comment still stands. You have 16 open questions which at least multiple got valid answers however you addresses non of them. Maybe you would still need to take the site's [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: The problem is that you ask for help, receive help, and don't acknowledge. After 16 such occurrences within a short time the best help you can expect is the advice not to be so rude. Go back to your previous 16 questions and select some answers where you got what you wanted. Comment on those which you feel fell short of your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you need as it adjusts only spacing and not scaling, but if you insert the text in a single cell table and remove the table borders, you can set the cell options to fit text :

[image]

Comment: it's a good idea,but i want input  a word with no table,and outpur a word can show me the code